# Javascript: Change background of all images inside div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change the background of all images inside a div with a JS function:

My div:

```
<div>
    <div id="avatar_container">
        <img src="a.png" onclick="myfunction()"  />
        <img src="b.png" onclick="myfunction()"  />
    </div>
</div>
```

My function:

```
function myfunction(){
    //I tried this two methods
    document.getElementById("avatar_container").getElementsByTagName('img').css({'background' : 'green'}); 
    document.getElementById("avatar_container").getElementsByTagName('img').style.backgroundColor = "green";        
}
```

Comment: [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a list of elements. You will have to use a loop to iterate over the elements. But why don't you add a class to `avatar_container` with a rule to set the background of all descending images? Like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8m54o1Lf/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's solve your problem

```
<div id="avatar_container">
    <img src="a.png"  class="myClass1"  />
     <img src="b.png"  class="myClass1"  />
</div>
```

Js: (important Notice: use js code after html codes)

```
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass1'), i;
    for (i in elems) {
            elems[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";  
        }
    }
```

but i suggestion you to use and learn Jquery ,

jquery is a Javascript Framework witch make everything's very easy for you with less coding

with Jquery You can do it simplest like this

```
$('#avatar_container .myClass1').css('backgroundcolor','green');
```

and if you wanna attach click event

```
 $('#avatar_container .myClass1').click(function() {
   $(this).css('backgroundcolor','green');
});
```

Comment: Don't use `for (... in ...)` for arrays

Comment: [`for (variable in object)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in): "The `for..in` statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed."; For arrays you should be using [`for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) instead